# Blender Crashes with Large Files on AWS g4dn.xlarge Instance

Tags: memory-management

Hello Blender Community,

I'm currently facing a challenging situation with Blender crashing when attempting to open a file under the following conditions:

- Due to insufficient performance on my local PC, I've opted to use AWS's NICE DCV for Windows (g4 and g5 with NVIDIA gaming driver) available here: [AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-67uoddn7zjdxu).
- The instance type I'm using is g4dn.xlarge.
- I've encountered this issue across Blender versions 4.1, 4.0, and the 3.6 LTS.
- The .blend file in question is quite large at 1.41GB. While it does open on my local machine (Windows 10, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K, 32GB RAM, GeForce GTX 1070), albeit slowly, it consistently crashes on the AWS instances mentioned above.
- I was able to open small files without any problems in the same environment.

Here is a snippet of the log showing the issue:

```
wmEvent type:260/WINDOW_DEACTIVATE, val:2/RELEASE, prev_type:214/RIGHT_ALT, prev_val:2/RELEASE, modifier={}, keymodifier:171, flag:{}, mouse:(373,117), utf8:'', pointer:000001D24E9A2B40
UI_menutype_draw: opening menu "TOPBAR_MT_editor_menus"
UI_menutype_draw: opening menu "TIME_MT_editor_menus"
UI_menutype_draw: opening menu "VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus"
Malloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_gpu_get_data, total 7682452824
Memoryblock free: attempt to free NULL pointer
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7687429472
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7693335240
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7699676632
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7705902176
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7712599344
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7719220096
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7724563376
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7730728968
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7736990200
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7741393736
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7747776360
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Calloc returns null: len=268435456 in imb_alloc_buffer, total 7753886656
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (<packed data>)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Malloc returns null: len=5906760 in acquire_data, total 7753896120
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FFC887C12DB
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FFC887C12DB
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FFC887C12DB
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FFC887C12DB
Module  : VCRUNTIME140.dll
Thread  : 00001150
Module  : VCRUNTIME140.dll
Writing: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\joined.crash.txt
Thread  : 00001708
Module  : VCRUNTIME140.Writing: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\joined.crash.txt
dll
Thread  : 00001a20
Module  : VCRUNTIME140.dll
Writing: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\joined.crash.txt
Thread  : 00001b88
Writing: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\joined.crash.txt
Error loading symbols C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\blender.pdb
        error:0xe06d7363
        size = 93384704
        base=0x00007FF7BE5A0000
Error loading symbols C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\blender.pdb
        error:0xe06d7363
        size = 93384704
        base=0x00007FF7BE5A0000
Error loading symbols C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\blender.pdb
        error:0xe06d7363
        size = 93384704
        base=0x00007FF7BE5A0000
Malloc returns null: len=5000 in opendir, total 7753896120
Malloc returns null: len=5000 in opendir, total 7753896120
```

Has anyone else faced a similar issue, or could anyone provide any insights into what might be causing these crashes? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It might help anyone who knows the answer if you attach the .blend file in question

Comment: Could it be that you are running out of memory on this machine ? It seems to be 16GiB, compared to 32GB on your local machine.

Comment: > It seems to be 16GiB, compared to 32GB on your local machine

Indeed, I thought it was good because it had a lot of VRAM, but having less RAM was a blind spot. I just tried it, but unfortunately, it didn't work on g4dn.2xlarge, g5.2xlarge, and also on g5.xlarge.

Comment: This is the data I'm trying to open. I hope it can be helpful.

https://beneficial-mandrill-7ed.notion.site/Blender-Crashes-with-Large-Files-on-AWS-g4dn-xlarge-Instance-packed-6b689ba015bc4d79b41d1197e9697697?pvs=4

Comment: As indicated in the log, it seems to crash when the VRAM is full.
https://i.gyazo.com/3f408255af389e640717da2b04842341.mp4